# Adding blank spaces to a list of strings at a specific position

Tags: python, string, list, function, list-comprehension

I am trying to process a list of strings in order to get all my strings with 8 characters. If a string has less than 8 characters I fill as many blank spaces as needed to get an 8 character long string before the last 4 characters. I wrote the following function and tried to apply it to a list of strings, but got a list with None values.

```
def lengthstring(string):
    if len(string) == 5:
        new_string = string[0] + "   " + string[1:5]
    elif len(string) == 6:
        new_string = string[0:2] + "  " + string[2:6]
    elif len(string) == 7:
        new_string = string[0:3] + " " + string[3:7]
    else:
        new_string = string

lp = ['7C246', '7B8451', 'NDKW0745', '5B06833']

labels_with_eight_characters = [lengthstring(string) for string in lp]
```

Thank you!

Comment: There is no `return` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you need a more concise version of the code:

```
def lengthstring(string):
    return (
        string if len(string) >= 8
        else string[:-4] + ' ' * (8 - len(string)) + string[-4:])


labels_with_eight_characters = list(map(lengthstring, lp))
print(labels_with_eight_characters)
```

This prints:

```
['7   C246', '7B  8451', 'NDKW0745', '5B0 6833']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you did not return values in your `lengthstring` function. After `new_string = string`, add `return new_string` and your code should run fine.

Comment: Thank you! :D Glad that it was that easy :D

Answer (score 0):

a little easier would be to use [rjust](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rjust.html)...

```
for loc in lp:
    print(loc.rjust(8, ' '))
```

Comment: OP wants the last 4 chars to be intact.

Comment: understood... just wasn't clear why the spaces were in the middle.  sometimes I create complicated solutions to easy problems.